# I need tips for increasing concentration for math study

Tags: soft-question

Any tips for increasing concentration? I find it difficult to concentrate for looong periods at a time, after having taken a long break from mathematics. Before I could sit for hours and do calculations and reading. Now I just put down the book or turn to a distraction.

Any biological, practical or philosophical tips would be much appreciated! I need to increase my concentration!

Comment: There are some tips but several are illegal in some parts of the world...coffee may help during those looooooong nights of intensive study, though.

Comment: I find regular exercise helps to increase my concentration and reduce the temptation of distractions.

Comment: @DonAntonio I think coffee makes me fidget and get stressed, not pleasant!

Comment: Well @FrederickG : fidget and stressed is better than asleep one day before final exam...

Answer (score 1):

Avoid computers, phones, and televisions. If you are studying independently, make yourself assignments for the chapter you're working on, and don't read ahead till you've finished.

Comment: So basically a library or cellar?

Comment: Or outdoors, perhaps.

Comment: Computers can be turned off.  They can also be given to friends for safekeeping.